# Didn't find class "com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver" unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, onesignal

I am using unity **2018.2.11f1** and latest **one signal sdk**. But the app crashes when i send notiication with this error **Unable to instantiate receiver com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver"**. But in my other project it is working perfectly that is in **unity 2018.3.8**. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Please compare all manifest files and the Plugins/Android folder of both the project.
2. Also, check all the firebase and AppId related settings in both projects.

Comment: Create separate project in the old version and try to do the same things